# Adding a database relation in order to decrease joins and increase performance

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I am using SQL Server 2008. My question is regarding relational database design.
I got the following tables and relations:

**Contract**: I have a 1-M relation with Laborer.  We expect like half
a million contract. A contract is business contract between two parties.

**Laborer**: Every group of laborers belongs to one contract. We expect
millions of laborers.

**Message**: Expected to contain millions of records. Messages are sent to 
contract parties about contracts and laborers.

**MessageContract**: A bridge table between Message and Contract, and
expected to have millions of records.

**MessageLaborer**: A bridge table between Message and Laborer, and
expected to have millions of records.

**Process**: has a 1-M relation with Message. Expected to eventually have
hundred thousands of records.

My question is whether I can add a relation between Process and MessageContract and MessageLaborer in addition to the relation between Process and Message, so when query contracts and laborers under processing, I will not have to add a join with Message.

Another example: MessageLaborer is having indirect relation with MessageContract. At anytime you can query database to get laborers under each contract message, but you will need 4 joins to do this. The other option is to create another relation between MessageLaborer and MessageContract so you only need one join.

Is this a common practice or a common mistake?

Comment: it sounds like a mistake.  adding a relation in order to simply reduce joins is either a denormalization, or a change in the logic that is now modeling something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only makes sense to have a bridge table between two relations when they have a many-to-many relationship -- it resolves the many-to-many into a one-to-many-to-one.

If you need to define a message and then send it to multiple contracts then use a bridge table between messages and contracts. If a message only applies to a single contract then no bridge table is required.

Do not introduce new tables to join relations that are naturally joined already. You'll break the ability of the normalised form to provide a single source of truth for every fact. However, if you had two child tables of a parent if would generally be fine to join between them without going via the parent table by joining on their foreign key columns.

Answer (score 1):

The most common mistake in database design is to add too many relations.  Implementing a 1:N relation is complex.  It is easy to write a client application to update a customer that always has two addresses.  It is much harder to write a client application for a customer with 0..N addresses.

For example, if a message can relate to at most one contract, you could remove the `MessageContract` table.  The client (or business layer) that creates a message now has one less table to worry about.  The client that displays the message can use a listbox instead of a gridview.  Much, much easier!

Answer (score -1):

You can think of relational database modelling process as making your system aware of part of the real world. So, if there is a relation in the real world your db has to know about, there should be a real database relation as well.

Don't add your database relation just because you will need a JOIN. This part belongs to query optimization.